# OpenSSL Ignore Self-signed certificate error

Tags: c++, c, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm writing a small program with the OpenSSL library that is suppose to establish a connection with an SSLv3 server. This server dispenses a self-signed certificate, which causes the handshake to fail with this message: "sslv3 alert handshake failure, self signed certificate in certificate chain."

Is there a way I can force the connection to proceed? I've tried calling SSL_CTX_set_verify like so:

```
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);
```

But it does not seem to change anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `SSL_VERIFY_NONE` disables certificate verification entirely. You probably don't want to do this as this leave you vulnerable to MITM attacks. The right thing to do is to add the self-signed certificate to the list of trusted certificates. (See SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations().)

Comment: By the way, the error message does not mean that the server's certificate is self-signed. It means you do not trust the root CA's certificate:

**X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN**
    _A self-signed certificate exists in the certificate chain. The certificate chain could be built up using the untrusted certificates, but the root CA could not be found locally._

Root CA certificates are always self-signed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default OpenSSL walks the certificate chain and tries to verify on each step, `SSL_set_verify()` does not change that, see tha man page. Quoting it:

> The actual verification procedure is performed either using the
>   built-in verification procedure or using another application provided
>   verification function set with SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback(3).

So the solution is to create a simple callback and set that one, so that you override all certificate-chain walking:

```
static int always_true_callback(X509_STORE_CTX *ctx, void *arg)
{
    return 1;
}

SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback(CTX, always_true_callback);
```

Comment: Just a few paragraphs below the quoted text: `If no verify_callback is specified, the default callback will be used. Its return value is identical to preverify_ok, so that any verification failure will lead to a termination of the TLS/SSL handshake with an alert message, if SSL_VERIFY_PEER is set.`
Your answer is incorrect, setting the verify mode to SSL_VERIFY_NONE should be enough.

Comment: @Spidey Did you read the question? It's given that SSL_VERIFY_NONE is *not* enough. Did you try it yourself? FYI the manual you quoted is for for `SSL_CTX_set_verify()`. But verification can fail is many more ways even if the *set_verify* callback always succeeds, that's why you have to set the more generic callback with `SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback()`.

Comment: Always returning `1` disables certificate verification entirely. This is the same as setting `SSL_VERIFY_NONE`. (i.e. @Spidey is right.) You probably don't want to do this as this leave you vulnerable to MITM attacks. The right thing to do is to add the self-signed certificate to the list of trusted certificates. (See SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations().)

Comment: @ErwanLegrand it's given in the question that SSL_VERIFY_NONE is not enough. The reason is that OpenSSL still walks the whole certificate chain, it still executes the verification procedure, it just does not call the callback ever. But still the procedure fails outside the callback. You have to call SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback(3) and set the callback using that one, to fully disable certificate-chain walking and checking.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried giving your app the server's CA certificate so that your app **can** verify the certificate chain?

Comment: Correct, although in this case the server uses a self-signed certificate, what the OP must make his app trust is not a CA certificate but the server's certificate.

Comment: My bad, the OP is wrong. The server certificate is not self-signed. The error message included in the question show the error is `X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN` which means that the self-signed certificate mentioned is not the server's cert but a root CA's cert.

Answer (score 2):

Check these OpenSSL Examples: http://www.rtfm.com/openssl-examples/

The **wclient.c** connects to any https page, for example:

```
wclient -h www.yahoo.com -p 443
```

If you run that with the default installation, you'll get a certificate error (you can use the -i flag to bypass the certificate check though).

To verify the certificate, you'll need to download the CA certificates (Verisign, Thawte, Equifax, etc), so google this file **cacert.pem**, download and rename it to **root.pem** and you'll be able to connect to a web server and validate its certificate.

Comment: Also, if you want to print the certificate, insert this line (in wclient.c) after the check_cert(ssl,host): X509_print_fp(stdout,SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl));

Comment: Correct, although in this case the server uses a self-signed certificate, what the OP must make his app trust is not a CA certificate but the server's certificate.

Comment: My bad, the OP is wrong. The server certificate is not self-signed. The error message included in the question show the error is `X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN` which means that the self-signed certificate mentioned is not the server's cert but a root CA's cert.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting SSL_set_verify?

```
SSL_set_verify(s, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've tried all of your suggestions and still no luck. I've pasted key portions of the program here:
http://pastebin.com/m78497bf3

Comment: Is the custom callback in your code being called? Does a breakpoint there get hit? Try with something other than verify none...

It's probably best for you to add that code snippet to your original question so that everything is self contained on here...

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing your own callback to `SSL_set_verify()` and then doing your own verification. It's less than ideal as I think you then need to do all of the verification and then allow the self signed error to be ignored, but you should be able to work out what the standard verify code does from the OpenSSL source and then simply pull it into your own verification callback and allow the specific error code...

Comment: If you're going to accept self-signed certificates, then the rest of the verification steps are pointless anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My sample client code ([link](http://bobah.net/d4d/source-code/networking/sss-client-socket)) works fine with self signed server cert. I have the below code after SSL_connect and have full control over self signed certificates acceptability in my client

```
SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_method());

// TCP connection and SSL handshake ...

/* Check the certificate */

rc = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
if(rc != X509_V_OK) {
  if (rc == X509_V_ERR_DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT || rc == X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN) {
    fprintf(stderr, "self signed certificate\n");
  }
  else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Certificate verification error: %ld\n", SSL_get_verify_result(ssl));
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: This leaves you vulnerable to MITM attacks! Any self-signed certificate is accepted if you do this. The errors you ignore are not raised if the certificate is trusted. The right thing to do is to add the self-signed certificate to the list of trusted certificates. (See SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations().)