# SSL/TLS without certificates

Tags: openssl, ssl

I'm working on a pet project that will (eventually, when it's done) allow for secure file transfers (there's more to it than just that, but the rest isn't particularly relevant).  I'd like to use the OpenSSL library, since it seems to be the most complete free cryptography library (and I need support for basic symmetric encryption and hashing, in addition to SSL/TLS).

I'm looking to implement a security scheme *similar* to SSH.  Basically, a user would connect to my computer with TLSv1 (SSLv3.1).  I'd like the connection to succeed regardless of security.  Then, I want to be able to inspect the public *key* (not an entire certificate) that the user used.  That key would be compared against known public keys, and if it matched, then the user would be allowed to access a certain set of commands.  If it didn't match, the user would have the option to use the connection to apply to have his/her public key added to my collection, but other than that would not be able to access my services.

I don't have any particular need for certificates here.  It would be much simpler for me if I could just skip all the certificate details and work only with the raw encryption keys.  This is because this model follows a web-of-trust model, not the hierarchical model used by most SSL/TLS connections, so I don't need any CA's or signed certificates.

Unfortunately, the documentation of most of OpenSSL is, well, nonexistent.  All the relevant articles I find seem to be occupied with setting up a "standard" SSL/TLS connection, where the server's certificate is verified all the way up to a set of root certificates.  This can be useful, but it's hard for me to figure out how to get these non-traditional SSL connections up and running.

Can anyone suggest any articles or documentation that might help me figure out how to accomplish this?

(The use of OpenSSL is not set in stone, and I could switch to another library if it provides a better way of accomplishing this, as well as hashing [SHA-512] and symmetric encryption [AES].  I'm aiming at targeting Linux, but it would be nice if the final product was portable to Windows so my friends could use it too.)

Comment: Comparing a public key against a list of public keys is essentially using a password, which defeats the entire PKI-ness of https and ssl.  The suggestion to create and use self-signed certs is a good one if you control both the client and server software (so you can configure the trust relationship).

Comment: @AdamLiss, no, it's not the same as the password: the user never has to send the private key, whereas the user would have to send the password. (And comparing self-signed certs in a list is pretty much the same as comparing their public keys.)

Comment: I'm not using the PKI though.  The idea is that if you're my "friend" (I have your public key/cert), then you can download files (that I specify) from my computer PLUS files that I can download from MY friends.  The catch is that you can't see where the files are coming from (that is, if A and B are friends, and B and C are friends, A can download from C through B, but does not know about C at all).  At least, that's the idea in a nutshell.  [OneSwarm](http://www.oneswarm.org/) gave me inspiration for this project.

Comment: Have you already decided on a language by the way? Have you looked into LibNSS too, it seems fairly well documented http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ref/ssl/?

Comment: I haven't completely decided on a language (I'm still working on which libraries I want to use, and the specification for the program/protocol), but it's likely that I'll use C.  I *might* use D instead.  It really depends on the libraries more than anything - the exact language doesn't matter much to me.

Comment: @Bruno: There is no private key in this scheme.  He's asking the user to transmit something, which he's searching for in a list.  It's cryptographically equivalent if the "something" is a password, a public key, or a red sock.  It's a simple lookup; no private key or signing is involved.

The better suggestion is not to _compare_ self-signed certs; it's to use them according to PKI standards, which means using the public key to validate the owner's private key.

Comment: @Ethan: the problem with your scheme is that public keys are, well, _public_: you can't use your own public key to assert your identity because it's assumed to be available to anyone.  The right way to authenticate a user is to ask him to encrypt some known data with his _private_ key; then you use his _public_ key to decrypt it.  That's exactly how digital signatures work using PKI.

Comment: @Adam, but that's the whole point.  When they establish an SSL/TLS connection with a public key, part of the handshake is encrypting some information with the public key for the ndoe on the other end to decrypt with their private key.  So the requirements to authenticate would be (1) you must have a public key that matches one in my database and (2) you must prove you have the private key that goes with your public key.

Comment: @Ethan, then are you building a mutual authentication scheme (that is, each side authenticates to the other)?  That's not clear to me from your original question, since PKI auth is very different from simply looking up a public key.  So it sounds as though you're using the public key as the User ID, and PKI auth to verify the user's identity.  Again, this would happen if you used self-signed certs

Comment: @Adam, correct.  I'm sorry if it wasn't clear - I assumed that any public key used to initiate an SSL/TLS connection would clearly be challenged by the host.

Comment: @AdamLiss, using a client certificate (via the `CertificateRequest`/`CertificateVerify` messages in TLS) is actually independent of a PKI. You can check whether-or-not you trust the certificate (via a PKI or by looking up a table or other) independently: the `CertificateVerify` mechanism will guarantee that the client has the private key for the public key certificate presented during the handshake anyway.

Comment: @Bruno, the way to verify a cert's validity is to check that each of the certs in the chain was signed with the parent's private key--that's PKI.  But don't confuse trust with identity: you may trust a cert, but _anyone_ can send that cert to you--it's a public entity.  In order to assert identity, the client must also sign it with its own private key.  Again, that's PKI.  As you noted, all of this happens as an SSL/TLS session is established.

Comment: @AdamLiss, I'm not getting confused. A pub key cert binds a pub key, an identifier and other attributes (e.g. purpose). The PKI defines how to verify the certs (i.e. how the trust chain works) + how some attribs should be interpreted. The `CertificateVerify` TLS message has nothing to do with that. It's the signature, with the client's priv key, of the concatenation of all the handshake msgs (incl client cert). It must be verifiable using the client cert pub key, that's it. Whether-or-not the server wants to trust the content of this cert is orthogonal (and usually done via a PKI).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on Eugene's answer (I would have put this as a comment, but it's a bit long)...

Having done this sort of things with the [FOAF+SSL project](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Foaf+ssl) (later renamed WebID), sticking with X.509 certificates makes the implementation easier, simply because most SSL/TLS stacks are designed with them in mind (and their API reflect this).

Last time I checked FOAF+SSL, the traditional PKI checks were still in place for the client to check the server certificate. Another option, similar to SSH, would be to accept the public key/certificate the first time you encounter it and warn the user when it changes. That's more or less the way SSH works anyway (in particular, I guess that few people actually check the key's fingerprint out of bands the first time they see it).

Considering just the client-certificate usage (although some of this could apply to server certs in a similar way):

- Most server libraries seem to be able to process X.509 certificates, but let you change the way they are verified (e.g. `X509TrustManager` in Java).
- Whilst you won't be able to trust anything the client-cert says until you have verified it otherwise, being able to embed some extra information (such as a Subject DN or Subject Alternative Name to see who the user claim to be) can help (a) the users organise their certs and (b) give a hint for the verifier to know what to look for. A bare public key can be hard to manage.
- A number of existing client tools (especially browsers) use X.509 certificates when doing SSL/TLS client authentication. Not much needs to be done to configure a client to use a self-signed X.509 cert (as opposed to a cert from a PKI). (There are very few tools that support OpenPGP for TLS, I'm not sure any are able to use it as a form of client certificate.)
- Since you won't be able to trust the cert without external checks, it doesn't matter whether it's self-signed or not (i.e. whether the issuer and the subject are the same), at least assuming the user wouldn't send you a cert with which it wouldn't agree (so it wouldn't have to be sealed by its own key). A consequence of that is that you can build a service to issue certs quite easily. In-browser key-generation, for example, is convenient for users who don't want to use `openssl` or `keytool` commands. [Here](https://github.com/harbulot/keygenapp/) is an example service that will issue a certificate with the SAN the user wants (there might be more recent versions if you check with the FOAF+SSL/[WebID](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebID) project). Whichever private key or issuer name such a service uses barely matters, but since browsers are designed around traditional PKIs, it doesn't make it easy to use really self-signed certificates.

There are also issues when it comes to asking for a specific client-certificate. The TLS 1.1 specification explicitly allows empty `certification authorities` (see [RFC 4346](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#section-7.4.4)), whereas the TLS 1.0 were silent on the subject. In practice, even with TLS 1.0, most client tools seem to be happy with an empty list (they'll just offer more choice). If you want your certificates for your system to be easily identifiable, you could use the same issuer DN for all these certs, even if they're not signed with the same private key in practice (again, since you would ignore the signature).

Comment: The idea is that I would generate an invite code and give that code to a friend.  Along with the code, I would enter some details about my new friend (specifically, an address at which they're located, like ethan.no-ip.org).  When they send in an "application", they use the invite code, and can also send a message.  The program would check to make sure the invite is correct and that the address I entered resolves to the origin of the application at the time it's created.  I can also make it so you manually inspect the message.  The idea is that this is how you validate new "friends".

Answer (score 2):

Use self-signed certificates - this is the same as "raw" keys but easier to manage (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256950/openssl-ignore-self-signed-certificate-error) regarding how to accept or not accept a self-signed certificate in openssl).

Comment: So the answer would be "There's no easy way to not use certificates at all.  It's easier to just use self-signed certificates."?  I guess that works.  I can still skip loading any root certificates though, right?

I guess the obvious follow-up is:  Can I force OpenSSL to **only** accept self-signed certificates?

Comment: @Ethan, there's no point restricting access to self-signed certs only (and rejecting the others). If you're willing to accept any self-signed certificate, you might as well accept anything, since you wouldn't be able to check the issuer DN is who they say they are (using only the cert), whether-or-not issuer DN = subject DN becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @Ethan in general SSL supports authentication with OpenPGP keys or with pre-shared secret key. But none of these will suit. As for accepting only self-signed - you can dynamically control what to trust and I guess among other checks OpenSSL should let you check if the certificate is self-signed (its Issuer and Subject fields must be identical).

Comment: @Bruno, I guess that makes sense if I'm ignoring the rest of the certificate anyways and just using the public key.