# openssl making ssl connection without certificate

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

Hi I want to make a basic ssl connection without using certificate with my client and server using  `c++`    and  `openssl` .  I have been trying with `SSL_connect`  and `SSL_accept` with no luck getting the handshake with the  `BIO`  object first. Should I even bother with any SSL functions if I am not using any certificates? I have been researching around and found `BIO`  wrapper for ssl and I am wondering is that is the way to go.

Comment: Why without certificate? What type of security you want? How will you protect without asymmetric cipher. Or you want some other key exchange mechanism like El-gamal?

Comment: I will be using keysharing for handshake but i don't know if using ssl functions will work on that

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619528/ssl-tls-without-certificates