# How do I dumb down SSL DNS verification?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, security, ssl

I have a very low security environment (sensor data on a LAN) that I am trying to add just a little bit of security on.

I am pretty sure this error is asking for proper DNS which is not available. Certs are self-signed with basically junk added to the FQDN.

I get the following error:

```
$ python3 twistedClientsocketSSL.001.py
Error during info_callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 315, in dataReceived
    self._checkHandshakeStatus()
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 235, in _checkHandshakeStatus
    self._tlsConnection.do_handshake()
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1906, in do_handshake
    result = _lib.SSL_do_handshake(self._ssl)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1288, in wrapper
    callback(Connection._reverse_mapping[ssl], where, return_code)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1103, in infoCallback
    return wrapped(connection, where, ret)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1216, in _identityVerifyingInfoCallback
    verifyHostname(connection, self._hostnameASCII)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/service_identity/pyopenssl.py", line 48, in verify_hostname
    obligatory_ids=[DNS_ID(hostname)],
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/service_identity/_common.py", line 245, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Invalid DNS-ID.")
builtins.ValueError: Invalid DNS-ID.

main function encountered error
Traceback (most recent call last):
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "twistedClientsocketSSL.001.py", line 18, in custom_trust
    response = yield treqish.get('https://192.168.1.7:1079')
twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure builtins.ValueError: Invalid DNS-ID.>]
```

client code:

```
import treq
from twisted.internet import defer, ssl, task
from twisted.web import client

@task.react
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def custom_trust(_reactor):
    # get root cert from pem file
    with open('keys/server.crt') as cert_file:
        trust_root = yield ssl.Certificate.loadPEM(cert_file.read())

    # ready made browser-like policy
    policy = client.BrowserLikePolicyForHTTPS(trustRoot=trust_root)

    agent = client.Agent(_reactor, policy)
    treqish = treq.client.HTTPClient(agent)

    response = yield treqish.get('https://192.168.1.7:1079')
    content = yield response.content()
    print(content)
```

corresponding server code:

```
$ cat twistedServersocketSSL.002.py    
import sys

from twisted.internet import endpoints, reactor, ssl
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.python.modules import getModule

class Example(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def render_GET(self, request):
        return u'Hello World'.encode('ascii')

# create SSL server from string
https_server = endpoints.serverFromString(
    reactor,
    'ssl:1079:interface=192.168.1.7:certKey=keys/server.crt:privateKey=keys/server_no_pass.key')

# start server
site = server.Site(Example())
https_server.listen(site)
log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
reactor.run()
```

How do I dumb down SSL DNS verification so I can get around this error or a decent low security solution thats light weight that gets plain text off a network socket connection?

Comment: "with basically junk added to the FQDN." your error comes from there. put the valid local hostname in the certificate if you want the name matching to work, or do not use a verification based on name and hence use something else in the certificate.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek there will never be anything close to a valid hostname available. its just not that kind of network. I will never be any higher than layer 2.

Comment: Then do not use "junk" as hostnames, just use a non-DV like certificate, that is like an OV with organization details. Or it seems that having a certificate has no value in your use case (a certificate is used to authenticate the remote end, when you want not just the confidentiality+integrity features but also authentication), so look about using TLS with a preshared key instead of a certificate maybe. Otherwise if your IP addresses are stable, use that as and ID instead of a name.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek i tried to feed it a 'fakeclient.myactualregisteredDomain.info', but nothing in that DNS is configured. so, it won't accept an unconfigured yet real(ish)/pretend FQDN. 'echo $hostname' is blank for the device. So my choices are empty or fake, and it doesn't like either.

Comment: also, the act of creating an individual key for each new client is way above the scope of my needs. I don't think SSL is the solution I am looking for.

Comment: fyi, setting hostname to match FQDN added in provisioning yields the same error. Its still all pretend, but its matching pretend.

Comment: I can try to say it again: if you put an hostname in the certificate it will get matched per rules in RFC6125:. So if you do that, as long as the name matches things will work. If it does not; it will never work. As simple as that; so as said again, do not use an hostname if that does not match your use case, but an IP address or something else, or just remove certificates and use bare keys. Have a look at part C.5 of RFC8446 (TLS 1.3). Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619528/ssl-tls-without-certificates covers that case.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I just deleted all the old certs, created new ones with 'pizero' as the FQDN. I set the same in /etc/hostname and then rebooted. Same error.

Comment: The code above uses an IP address in the URL, did you change it to use the name? If you do troubleshooting show in your question exactly what the client does, the certificate it gets and the complete error message.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek oh wow, I can't use that. If I have to redo cert upon an IP address change, I'll delete the entire system first. That is completely non functional for my purposes. I would of never have gone there. Thank you sincerely for pointing out the error but that is a show stopper. It cannot even be considered.

Comment: PS, changing the FQDN to include IP fix the error and opened up another can of worms  https://bpaste.net/show/45db77c99eb8  I already have an ssh tunnel up.