# Create new NativeFunction and use it then

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, frida

I am wondering: how can I allow self-signed certs while app using `openssl` library?

I saw that code which disables certificate validation [StackOverflow question/answer hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256950/openssl-ignore-self-signed-certificate-error)

```
static int always_true_callback(X509_STORE_CTX *ctx, void *arg)
{
  return 1;
}
```

This is the method, where I should put this new method, which always returns 1
[image]

But I don't have any idea how can I create that method using Frida

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to create functions in Frida. What you can do is compile your c code to an .so library that contains this function and use Frida to load it into the process. Then you have the function and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish your goal

TL;DR

```js
var SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback = Module.findExportByName('libssl.so', 'SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback');
Interceptor.attach(SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback, {
  onEnter: function(args) { 
    Interceptor.replace(args[1], new NativeCallback((_arg1, _arg2) => {
      return 1;
    }, 'int', ['pointer', 'pointer']);
  },
});
```

Hook `SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback`, once it's called intercept `*cb`
and replace the return value.

```js
Interceptor.attach(SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback, {
  onEnter: function(args) { 
    Interceptor.attach(args[1]/* *cb */, {
      onLeave: function(retval) {
        retval.replace(1);
      }
    }); 
  },
});
```

replace the bytecode

```js
Interceptor.attach(SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback, {
  onEnter: function(args) { 
    // add a condition so you will patch only once
    Memory.patchCode(args[1], 64, code => { 
      const cw = new Arm64Writer(code, { pc: args[1] });
      cw.putMovRegU64('x0', 1);
      cw.putRet();
      cw.flush();
    });
  },
});
```

replace the function with CModule

```js
const cm = new CModule(`
void ret1(void) {
  return 1;
}
`);


Interceptor.attach(SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback, {
  onEnter: function(args) { 
    Interceptor.replace(args[1], cm.ret1);
  },
});
```